# SQL Transaction Management

Tags: c#, sql, .net, transactions

I am writing a module in C# and It requires to use SQL transactions as it has more DML operations and I am not using stored procedures because the current module involves the dependencies on other modules.

The dependent modules take in a SQL connection as a parameter and receive it from callee.
Now the problem is, I've already set up a transaction to a connection, which I could not use that in dependent modules because it has no transactions.

Now should I make the dependent modules transaction specific or should I create new connection for dependent modules.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Why not pass the transaction object as another parameter to the dependent modules? Infact, transaction object has connection information as well.

Comment: @Hunter Yes, thats the way and for 'standalone sql read modules', I plan to create dedicated sqlconnection( as the connection is offered from connection pool)